# MVVM performance: do not dispose View when using DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have performance issue and I need help to overcome it.

There is a window which displays different views (user controls) using `ContentControl`. I have bunch of ViewModels and corresponding `UserControl` bound via `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:ViewModelPageA}">
    <l:UserControlPageA/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:ViewModelPageB}">
    <l:UserControlPageBk/>
</DataTemplate>
```

This creates views depending on which ViewModel is displayed now.

One of `UserControl` has quite comprehensive `ListView` (a lot of bindings, triggers, etc). When switching to this user control ViewModel there is a significant delay (over a second).

I looked into *virtualization* already, but it doesn't looks like my concern: ViewModel persist between switches, there are only 100 of items and there is no performance problem after user control is rendered. Actually there is a small delay when using <kbd>PgUp</kbd><kbd>PgDown</kbd>, which looks to me like some sort of virtualization (`ListViewItems` are not created for invisible items) .

So problem is with initial view loading. It takes too much time to load. And will take more, as only 50% of bindings/triggers are done so far.  Without items loading is nearly instant.

In winforms e.g. without MVVM I kept views (forms) in memory and switches between them. Maybe this is what I should do in wpf too (to keep view of this problematic ViewModel alive)?

Question: considering said about (if there are no better alternatives to improve performance) how can I reuse view when using MVVM and data templating?

---

Predicting comments "show us some code" here is something to gives you idea about `ListView` complication:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <!-- cell template, there are many of such -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplateA">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandA, ElementName=listView}"
                            Visibility="{Binding IsCommandAVisible}" l:ButtonBehavior.SelectListViewItemOnFocus="True">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <Grid>
                                <!-- some simple vector graphic -->
                                <Path Width="13" Height="13" ...
                                      Visibility="{Binding IsExpanded, Converter={l:BoolToVisibilityHiddenConverter}, ConverterParameter=CollapsedInverted}"/>
                                <Path Width="13" Height="13" ...
                                      Visibility="{Binding IsExpanded, Converter={l:BoolToVisibilityHiddenConverter}, ConverterParameter=Collapsed}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Button>
                    <!-- more of such buttons -->
                </StackPanel>
                <!-- more of elements using visibility binding -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <!-- many columns using different cell templates -->
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" CellTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplateDate}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- and a lot of triggers here -->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What's in Items, where does it come from, and how is it loaded?

Comment: `Items` is `ObservableCollection<Items>` which persist between ViewModel switches, it contains ~100 items. `Item` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and it contains ~20 properties which are used in bindings (mostly to `Visibility`).

Comment: All useful, but I was angling more towards 'is Items loaded from an external source'? Have you ruled out latency from disk loading/web fetching/etc?

Comment: @goobering, yes I did. When I say *persistent* I mean it's not changing.

Comment: I think I'd consider pagination on Items - would this be workable? It might also be worth taking a look at the vector drawings on each Item. WPF isn't the fastest drawing engine in the world. It may be less time consuming to use image files rather than generating artwork on each Item.

Comment: Do you commands have an expensive CanExecute method?

Comment: @Dominik, only one command, removing it doesn't change anything. Btw I don't have binding errors (predicting possible comment).

Comment: @goobering, reducing number of items surely helps. And it seems I wasn't correct about conclusion with `ListViewItem` virtualization - all items are processed load and, why would slowdown on load increases for invisible items? There are not many buttons displayed at same time and graphic is rather simple (triangle, rectangle, circle, etc), consisting of few visuals packed into [StreamGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx) already (fastest way afaik). Btw, check my question, do you think persistant view (no loading) could be a solution?