# WPF - MVVM DataTemplate load to memory for reuse

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I have a window which has several different `DataTemplate` that are load to a `ContentControl` based on a `RadioButton` (The `RadioButton` sends a command to the ModelView which sets the `Content` property of the `ContentControl`.

It works well, but now several views contain a "heavy" object ([Eyeshot CAD viewer](http://www.devdept.com/eyeshot)).

Switching to any of these view causes a delay (at this moment there's absolutely zero logic in the whole software other than the view/view model)

Is there a way to load the view and the heavy control to memory once and then reuse it when switching to its view? (The `ViewModel` of that view is currently a singleton but that doesn't help)

```
<DockPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="160" Margin="0,0,0,12">
        ... Removed for clarity
    </StackPanel>

    <ContentControl x:Name="Tabs" Content="{Binding SelectedTabViewModel}" Margin="0,12,0,12"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I would vote it as duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30033162/1997232), but I don't get an answer myself. What I am currently doing is waiting for first render (which occurs in another `ContentControl`) before switching the view (during waiting you can show some animation to entertain user): `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ... , DispatcherPriority.Render);` (where `...` is a part what makes second `ContentControl` replacing the first..).

Answer (score 0):

On your DataTemplate, you can set the attribute x:Shared="True", this will allow the framework to reuse the visual control (inside the datatemplate) for another ContentPresenter.

This doesn't load the component at starting, but, this reuse it once instantiated.